# How to update the value of a column in r without replacing it

Tags: r

I looking to update a value within a column in r but it currently replaces it.

For example:

Subjects dataframe:

```
 Maths | English | Science | History |  Class

 0.1    |  0.2   |  0.3    |  0.2    |   Y2

 0.9    |  0.5   |  0.7    |  0.4   |   Y1
```

This is my code but currently, it only replaces the number above with a 1 and doesn't add to it.

```
classpred$Maths[grepl("^Y9$",classpred$class)] <- 1
```

I would like this output:

```
 Maths | English | Science | History |  Class

 1.1    |  0.2   |  0.3    |  0.2    |   Y9

 0.9    |  0.5   |  0.7    |  0.4   |   Y10
```

Comment: Please read up on `dput()` as it really helps folks who try to help others since it gives us your actual data and doesn't force you to be a carpenter (i.e. build tables by hand). It's not adding 1 because you didn't tell it to. You just assigned 1 to it. Try `classpred$Maths[grepl("^Y9$",classpred$class)] <- classpred$Maths[grepl("^Y9$",classpred$class)]  + 1`

Comment: ah perfect thanks, that was it. thanks very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem you are having here is with assignment. The operator `<-` in your case assigns 1 to the indexed value as opposed to adding 1 which is why @hrbrmstr solution works by changing `<-` to `+`. Take this simplified example:

```
x <- c(2:10) #dummy sequence
x[3] # index 3rd value in sequence
x[3] <- 1 # replace 3rd value with 1
x # value that was 4 is now 1
x[3] <- x[3]+1 # index 3rd value and add 1 to that value
x # value that became 1 is now 2
```

If you need to do a lot of this kind of manipulation on large datasets you might find a tidyverse solution becomes easier like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
class_df <- data.frame(maths = c(1,2,3),
                       english = c(3,2,1),
                       class = c("yr_9", "yr_10", "yr_11"))
class_df <- class_df %>%
  mutate(maths = case_when(class == "yr_9" ~ maths +1, TRUE ~ as.numeric(maths)))
```

Check out this resource for info https://jules32.github.io/2016-07-12-Oxford/dplyr_tidyr/

Cheers!